# Recursively go through directories and files in bash + use wc

Tags: regex, bash, recursion, find, wc

I need to go recursively through directories. First argument must be directory in which I need to start from, second argument is regex which describes name of the file.

ex. `./myscript.sh directory "regex"`

While script recursively goes through directories and files, it must use wc -l to count lines in the files which are described by regex.

How can I use find with -exec to do that? Or there is maybe some other way to do it? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `find`:

```
$ find DIR -iname "regex" -type f -exec wc -l '{}' \;
```

Or, if you want to count the total number of lines, in all files:

```
$ find DIR -iname "regex" -type f -exec wc -l '{}' \; | awk '{ SUM += $1 } END { print SUM }'
```

Your script would then look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 - name of the directory - first argument
# $2 - regex - second argument

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
  echo Usage: ./myscript.sh DIR "REGEX"
  exit
fi

find "$1" -iname "$2" -type f -exec wc -l '{}' \;
```

**Edit:** - if you need more fancy regular expressions, use `-regextype posix-extended` and `-regex` instead of `-iname` as noted by @sudo_O [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15678462/782609).

Comment: `-iname` doesn't support `regexp` it uses `shell globbing`

Comment: inside the script:


#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne "2" ]; then
    echo "wrong number of arguments!"
    echo "$0 <directory> <regex ex. *.txt>"
    exit
fi

echo $0
echo $1
echo $2

find $1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '$2' -type f -exec wc -l '{}' \; 

it should check subfolders included in first directory which is passed as argument

Comment: im sorry, im new here..

this will do, but, the script must also check subfolders included in directory which is passed as argument

Comment: @user2219046 - `find` will look into subfolders.

Comment: @kamituel you misunderstand the option `-iname` doesn't use `regexp` at all, you need to use `-regex` for that. `-name` and `-iname` work with shell globbing.

Comment: @sudo_O - I know, that's why I pointed to your answer and not just added this to mine. I'll make it more clear in an answer in a sec. In my understanding shell globbing is a form of a regex, just not a posix one.

Comment: @sudo_O - hm, in fact, you're right. Apparently thr name `regular expression` is used only for a specific syntax. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @kamituel no problem, globbing and regexp are similar but certainly not the same. Just fix your answer, I have removed mine.